# Best way of reliably SSHing to a remote roaming linux host

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, remote-access

I have a remote linux host that moves around the world on a boat. When the boat docks in a port the boat's network connects to (essentially) public wi-fi. I need to be able to administer the remote host when it is able to phone home.

I think what I need to do is set up the remote host to connect to a central VPN when it can. I then should be able to connect to the same VPN and see it and then SSH to it.

Is that right?

What's the best/easiest/most reliable way of doing this?

Comment: +1 "I have a remote linux host that moves around the world on a boat." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a VPN set up already, it would be simpler to SSH from the boat back into your local system, and leave a *reverse* port-forward in place:

```
ssh popeye@dryland -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 -N
```

Then ssh to localhost:2222 on your local system  will connect you to the boat, as long as the ssh session is open. [Restart the ssh as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies), though sleep if you have a way to detect that there is no network.
Use RSA/DSA keys, and/or chrooted user to limit exposure to your system if required.

If you need more than that you could set up a *Tunnel* using a `tun` device, which gives you something closer to a VPN using just SSH: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN

Comment: Thanks that's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set a DynDNS I think that your approach is reasonable.